# Клик по ссылке с повышением рейтинга

Tags: php

Кто-нибудь может показать код, чтобы при клике по ссылке `<a href="http://#">Нужная ссылка</a>` повышался ее рейтинг среди других ссылок (r++). Просто увеличить переменную рейтинга на 1? Будут вопросы, уточняйте. Все на php.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можно с помощью MySQL , создаем таблицу reyt в нее тыкаем id, и username
дальше делаем вот так:

<a href="http://#">Нужная ссылка</a> <-- в ней пишем код:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO reyt (username) values('".$_SESSION['username']."')");

    echo "<script>location.href='http://';</script>";
```

и потом где то выводим количество голосов

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM reyt"); 
 $sql2 = @mysql_fetch_array($sql);

 if(!$sql2) 
{ 
  echo "Где то появилась ошибка - ".mysql_error()."<br>"; 
  echo $sql; 
} 
 echo $sql2['count'];
```

Comment: Я посмотрел твои вопросы , и сразу возник у меня вопрос, ты играл или играешь в лигу17 ?

Comment: @oOKomarOo не учите плохому ...

Comment: Все вокруг да около, напишите конкретный код, а @shurlik если умный попробуйте сами.

Comment: @Семен - не идите к @Prikol 'у :DDD

Comment: нас уже много =)